# How can I add youtube autoplay to a [embed=videolink] code?

Tags: youtube, autoplay

How can I add youtube autoplay to this embedded code?

```
[embed=videolink]{"video":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDVQvme5tb0","width":"400","height":"225"}[/embed]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`[embed=videolink]{"video":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDVQvme5tb0&autoplay=1","width":"400","height":"225"}[/embed]`

I added "&autoplay=1" to the end of the link.